# iOS Framework: How do I include libraries so the project that uses the framework won't have to

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

So I decided to consolidate some shared code and classes in a framework using [this approach](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework)

It works fine, but it annoys me that the project that uses the framework has to include various libraries that the framework sues (sqlite, zlib...). Is there a way to include these in the framework, so the client project won't have to?

Comment: would using Cocoapods simplify? The appeal of static usually is PITA but no conflicts.

Comment: +1 for the question!! So your framework requires these libraries? And are the libraries that we are talking about 3rd party libraries or provided by Apple.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, they are required (ZIP compression and SQL table read/write), and yes they are provided by apple. I will look into Cocoapods. Frankly it's at most an annoyance, as they required project setup is minimal, but it's still less than friction free.